# How would I go about preforming actoins after "Next" button is clicked with a Jbutton setup like this?

Tags: java, swing, interface

I found this nice two button interface using javax.swing which I use for my program which will ask a series of questions. I got the question box all set-up but I need to make it go to a second interface after this one.

So I want the next button to preform a piece of code when pressed. Here is my code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingJPanelDemo extends JFrame {
String letter = "apple";
private JLabel LetterTest = new JLabel(Main.text);
private JButton NextButton = new JButton("Next");
private JButton NoButton = new JButton("No");

public SwingJPanelDemo() {
    super("Is This Your Letter?");

    // create a new panel with GridBagLayout manager
    JPanel newPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    // add components to the panel
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;     
    newPanel.add(LetterTest, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    newPanel.add(NextButton, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    newPanel.add(NoButton, constraints);

    // set border for the panel
    newPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Is This Your Letter?"));

    // add the panel to this frame
    add(newPanel);

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set look and feel to the system look and feel
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new SwingJPanelDemo().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

How would I go about preforming actions after a button is pressed when using this kind of setup for an interface?

BTW: if there are any things you think are mistaken o that could be done better help is always appreciated but not requested

Comment: You need to add an actionListener?

Comment: Where and how, I never came across an interface like this (Actually very inexperienced with interfaces in Java) and it just worked so I used this one.

Comment: Please go and read a [basic tutorial on Swing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=java+swing+tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an ActionListener to your nextButton.  There are at least two common patterns

With an anonymous class

```
nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    //Your code to do something here 
  }
});
```

With a custom ActionListener class:

```
class MyNextButtonActions implements ActionListener
{

    // lots of rich method etc that code the meaning of life

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //code to trigger on click, using all your lovely methods
    }

}
```

which you then add to your button where you create the GUI i.e.

```
nextButton.addActionListener(new MyNextButtonActions());
```

A decent tutorial on all this is available for the [Swing framework here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). You can get very creative - for instance you could make your SwingJPanelDemo class implement ActionListener and add it as an ActionListener for all its components.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to import java.awt.event.*;, then you add an actionlistener to you're jbutton by doing

```
NextButton.addActionListener(new MyFirstActionListener());
```

Next we have to make the MyFirstActionListener() class.  So anywhere inside your class is good.. perhaps in between the main method and your constructor, make it like so: and make sure it implements the ActionListener interface.  The ActionListener interface only demands 1 method; the actionPerformed method, which takes an ActionEvent object as a parameter.

```
private class MyFirstActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String whatIsWrittenOnTheButton = e.getActionCommand();
        if(whatIsWrittenOnTheButton.equals("Next")) {
            System.out.println("You pressed the \'Next\' JButton.");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == NextButton) {
            System.out.println("Here is a 2nd message upon pressing next");
        }
    }
}
```

e.getActionCommand() will return a string that represents what was written on the pressed button, and e.getSource() will return an object.   This is particularly handy if you use the same actionlistener for multiple different buttons; it's a means to distinguish between them.